# JavaScript image array in NetBeans

Tags: javascript, html, netbeans

I am a very new coder and even newer to Stack so please help me out if my question is bad or not understandable! 
I have been following a number of tutorials on this site and others on creating a JavaScript slideshow gallery for a website project I am making for school. I have the html written up, the first image will appear as it is loaded through html, but the debug console keeps saying that it is receiving empty responses when I try to run the webpage through the Chrome Connector. All that appears on the site is an empty image holder.

I reckon it's either something to do with NetBeans and my file structure within the project that it can't find the files or my code, but I've tried every method I've seen to load the images to the array. I even wiped and loaded a whole new set of images! No joy. I just can't figure out what is going on, every tutorial makes it look so easy! My file tree in netbeans is basic and the HTML and css files find the images no problem! I tried loading a screenshot of the file tree but i'm not allowed. Basically my photos are in a folder called images in the Site Root folder.

```
var bigPictureArray = [];

bigPictureArray[0]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[0].src='images/cup1.jpe)';
bigPictureArray[1]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[1].src='images/cf1.jpeg';
bigPictureArray[2]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[2].src='images/cf2.JPG';
bigPictureArray[3]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[3].src='images/cf3.jpg';
bigPictureArray[4]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[4].src='images/cf4.jpeg';
bigPictureArray[5]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[5].src='images/cf5.jpeg';
bigPictureArray[6]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[6].src='images/cf6.jpeg';
bigPictureArray[7]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[7].src='images/cf7.jpeg';
bigPictureArray[8]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[8].src='images/cf8.jpeg';
bigPictureArray[9]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[9].src='images/cf9.jpeg';
bigPictureArray[10]= new Image();
bigPictureArray[10].src='images/cf10.jpeg';


//function to display image slideshow
// found on youtube @ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MifpF7p1P0
   var bpa_k = 0;
   var bpa_elem;


   function bpaNext(){
       bpa_k++;
       bpa_elem.style.opacity = 0;
      if(bpa_k > (bigPictureArray.length -1)){
          bpa_k = 0;
      } 
      setTimeout("bpaSlide()", 1500);
   }
   function bpaSlide(){
       bpa_elem.innerHTML=bigPictureArray[bpa_k];
       bpa_elem.style.opacity = 1;
       setTimeout("bpaNext()", 2000);
   }



////the tutorial i used added this to the html files to load the slideshow in script tags

        <img src="cup1.jpe" id="bpa" alt="slideshow">
    <script>
       bpa_elem = document.getElementById("bpa");
       bpaSlide();
    </script>
```

again sorry if my question is a mess or the problem is ridiculous. I've been looking at this so long I am almost blind to it! I'm probably missing a really basic thing!

Comment: Might not have anything to do with it ..  But a path relative to document root is always the preferred method.  So instead of `images/image1.png`  You'd start with a slash and move all the way down to the images folder ..  IE `/images/image1.png`

Comment: Ritesh Karwa Thanks for your reply. I just tried that and the Browser Log just returned errors saying it can't find the images with that file path when it was showing no errors before. I'm having other issues with NetBeans not dynamically altering the DOM with other code which I'm pretty sure is right so I don't know what is going on right now.